# Setting target for Iframe using Ajax and Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, iframe

I am using zend-framework, iframe, ajax and jquery to call an url when a DIV is clicked.

I am using an iframe as follow

```
<iframe src="http://localhost.test.com/public/index/listen-message" name="listenMsg" height="120" width="600">
                            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                        </iframe>
```

I used following code for DIV

```
<div target="listenMsg" class="text" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
......
</div>
```

And for JQuery I write following code.....

```
$(".text").click(function()
{
    var clickedDiv = $(this).attr("id");

    var id=$(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost.test.com/public/index/listen-message",
        data: id,
        success: function(data){

        }
        });
        return false;
});
```

But When I click the DIV "text" control goes to http://localhost.test.com/public/index/listen-message but the result is not shown in the IFRAME....?

What may be the possible problems....?

Please provide some code, links and ideas......

Thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to this answer - Although there is an error in the code:

```
$('iframe[name="listenMsg"]').contents().find("body").html("your message");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should append the returned result to your iframe. ATM your ajac-call does nothing in the success function.

Just try

<strike>success: function(data){ $("#listenMsg").append(data); }</strike>

Edit:

I think i got your question wrong. You want to set the target dynamically, right?

Then use

<strike>success: function(data){ $("#" + $(this).attr('target')).append(data); }
and add `id="listenMsg"` to your iframe</strike>

```
    target = $(this).attr('target');
    $('body', window.frames[target].document).append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('iframe[name="listenMsg"').contents().find("body").html("your message");
```